# There is no continuous random variable $X$ for which Chebyshev's inequality is an equality for all $k>0$

Tags: probability

How can I show that there can not be a continuous random variable $X$ such that we have equality in Chebyshev's inequality for all $k>0$?

I think that it can be show find the probability of $P(|X-\mu|>ks)$ for any $k$ and compare it to $1/k^2$

Comment: For $k<\sigma$, that would mean $P(|X-\mu|\ge k)=\frac{\sigma^2}{k^2}>1$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Creation of matter!! Universe expansion!! Bazinga!!!